# How to access twodimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, c

I have a graph, which is represented by a two-dimensional array:

```
int graph[9][9] = { {INFINITY, 4, INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY, 8, INFINITY},
                        {4, INFINITY, 8, INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY, 11, INFINITY},
                        {INFINITY, 8, INFINITY, 7, INFINITY, 4, INFINITY, INFINITY, 2},
                        {INFINITY, INFINITY, 7, INFINITY, 9, 14, INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY},
                        {INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY, 9, INFINITY, 10, INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY},
                        {INFINITY, INFINITY, 4, 14, 10, INFINITY, 2, INFINITY, INFINITY},
                        {INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY, 2, INFINITY, 1, 6},
                        {8, 11, INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY, 1, INFINITY, 7},
                        {INFINITY, INFINITY, 2, INFINITY, INFINITY, INFINITY, 6, 7, INFINITY} };
```

This graph is passed into my class as an **int*pointer** like this

```
dijkstra::dijkstra(int* grapharray, int number_nodes)
{
    this->grapharray = grapharray;
    this->number_nodes = number_nodes;
}
```

In order to access the array i have made a variable

`int** graph=&grapharray;`

which allows me to access

```
graph[0][2]
graph[0][5]
```

and so on but not

```
graph[1][7]
```

How can i access the graph in both dimensions?

Comment: You need to change the declaration of your function to dijkstra::dijkstra(int** grapharray

Comment: @Roman2452809 No. A 2D array does not decay to pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you may want to consider using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.  It's easier to pass to functions.